# How to typehint a generic function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Say I want to define something in Python works exactly the same as the following function in Java:

```
public <T> void func(T a, T b):
     ...
```

This code simply means that `func` can take any `a` and `b` as input as long as they have the same data type.

Python doesn't have an explicit type check itself, but now I am using mypy to check my code. My attempts are as follows:

```
T = TypeVar('T')

def func(a: Generic[T], b: Generic[T]):
         ...
func(1, 3)  # this should be a legal input since 1 and 3 are both int
```

and

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Generic[T]):
    pass

def func(a: A[T], b: A[T]):
    ...
func(1, 3)
```

However, mypy reports errors for both of them. Is there a way for us to define such generic function just as in Java to pass mypy check? I know for the purpose of sanity check for my code, I can also check whether `type(a)` equals `type(b)` inside the function, but this is not my purpose. I am specifically interested in my question as it is, i.e., how to define such a generic function to pass mypy check?

Comment: not sure whether this will answer your question, Singledispatch could work. https://medium.com/@shopnilsazal/generic-function-in-python-with-singledispatch-b75cae6505dd

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but I think the issue is how your using the `T`. In the first example, it should be `def func(a: T, b: T):` - the type is `T`, not `Generic[T]`. In the 2nd example you've defined a generic class, `A`, but an `int` is not an `A` so mypy correctly won't let you pass an `int` when an `A[T]` is expected.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That Java function doesn't actually do what you want it to, and a Python equivalent wouldn't do what you want it to either.

You want to make sure that the Java function is always called with two arguments of the same type, but *any* two objects you could possibly pass it share a type. Specifically, any two objects are instances of `Object`. (`null` and primitives complicate things a little, but they won't stop calls from type-checking.) Any call will type check, and your attempt to use generics won't do a thing.

Similarly, the Python equivalent would be

```
def func(a: T, b: T):
    ...
```

and like the Java code, any call will type check, because any two objects are instances of `object`.

---

There's no way to specify a constraint of `type(a) is type(b)` with type annotations. It's usually the wrong constraint, anyway. What you usually want to specify is that the arguments are compatible with each other in some way. Unfortunately, there isn't really a good way to do that either.

For example, if you wanted to specify that two arguments are comparable with each other in Java, that would be

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void func(T a, T b) {...}
```

However, Python type variables don't support parameterized bounds like that.